# How to make a flutter oauth request

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a http request using oauth. I am trying to get infor mation feom Woocommerce. I have both the consummer key and consummer secret, but I cannot figure out how I should use them. I

I have tried https://github.com/hitherejoe/FlutterOAuth but it doesn't work with flutter version 2+. I also tried every other solution i could find, but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that package looks very outdated. The [OpenID_Client](https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client) package providers helper methods for the discovery endpoint of your domain (eg `https://{yourdomain}/.well-known/openid-configuration/.`)

An example of performing a token request without opening an external or embedded browser would be:

```
final oidUri = Uri.parse(_wooCommerceUrl).replace(path: '/');
final issuer = await Issuer.discover(oidUri);

final body = Map<String, dynamic>{
   'clientId': 'your_client_id',
   'clientSecret': 'your_client_secret',
   'grantType': 'some_grant_type',
   'scope': 'some_scope',
};

final headers = <String, String>{'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};

final res = await Client().post(issuer.metadata.tokenEndpoint, body: body, headers: headers);
```

Best of luck!